# VBA MS Access- Run-time error 3129 "Operation not valid/allowed"

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-access, scripting

so I am getting that error message at "Set EXO_Model....". What I am trying to do is say that if that field from that table has X value, then...... But I think I am missing something very basic.

So I would like the variables that I have set to store the hypotetical next value of each field for future entries. Then, performe the conditional to define the default value of SPT for each situation.

```
Option Compare Database

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Macro1
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Command1_Click()
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim db As DAO.Database



Set db = CurrentDb()

Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Table Special procurement type")

Set EXO_Model = tdf.Fields("Drop List").Value  '<------Error

Set Material_Type = tdf.Fields("Material Type").Value

Set Plant_of_Origin = tdf.Fields("Plant of Origin").Value

SPT = tdf.Fields("Special procurement type").DefaultValue

If EXO_Model = "TOLLING - FG" Then

    SPT = 30
    
ElseIf EXO_Model = "TURNKEY - FG" Then

    SPT = ""

ElseIf EXO_Model = "TURNKEY - LL" Then
    
    SPT = "\"

ElseIf EXO_Model = "TOLLING - LL" And Plant_of_Origin = "004 - BleBle" Then

    SPT = "L2"

ElseIf EXO_Model = "TOLLING - LL" And Plant_of_Origin = "007 - BlaBla" Then

    SPT = "C2"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That's just not what table defs do.

Answer (score 0):

TableDef fields don't have values, they represent the definition of the column.

To read values, you open a **Recordset**.

If this is in a form, you get the values of the current record like this:

```
EXO_Model = Me("Drop List").Value
```

---

Ok, I start to understand what you are trying to do.
You can't define default values like this.

You can do this in the form code, in the `SPT_GotFocus()` event. Read the values of the other fields as shown, calculate the default value as you have in your code, then set `SPT.Value`.

Comment: Then I am missing how to access a table and a field. Could you propose an example of how it would look for one of the fields? So that I can complete? To clarify, I am ot trying to read values but to set a rule for future records. Basically set a default value for a field with multiple conditions

Comment: Hi Andre, it's not a form, it's a table.

Comment: Well, you can't do that. @Joseph -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898479/setting-a-default-value-for-a-field-based-on-two-number-values-in-different-fiel

Comment: and if instead of a table it was a query which generates a table? In that case it could be done?